# sqlalchemy print results instead of objects

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to print the results of my query to the console, with the below code, but it keeps returning me the object location instead.

```
test = connection.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "my_table" WHERE Code = 08001)')
print(test)
```

Result that I get is - `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x000002108508B278>`

How do I print out the `value` instead of the object?

Reason I am asking is because I want to use the value to do comparison tests. 
EG:

```
if each_item not in test:
    # do stuffs
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this, `test` contains all the rows returned by your query.

If you want something you can iterate over, you can use `fetchall` for example. Like this:

`test = connection.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "my_table" WHERE Code = 08001)').fetchall()`

Then you can iterate over a list of rows. Each row will contain all the fields. In your example you can access fields by their position. You only have one at position one. So that's how you can access `1`:

```
for row in test:
    print(row[0])
```

Comment: Hmm, This returns me `0`. Not sure why

Comment: Okay. I think I know why. it is stored in SQL as a `string` so, that is the reason why it returned `0` :)

Comment: It makes sense, if it would be a number you wouldn't have a leading zero. When i reproduced the issue, I used a `number`, not a `string`.

Comment: What if there's no returned rows? Like in a `BEGIN/END` clause? `sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`

Comment: how do you print the sql in this case? using that test

Answer (score 1):

`test` is an object containing the rows values.  So if the column's name is `value`, you can call it using `test.value`.

If you're looking for more "convenient" way of doing so (like iterating through each column of `test`), you'd have to explicitly define these functions (either as methods of `test` or as other functions designed to iterate through those types of rows).

Answer (score -1):

This is a way as mentioned above for a raw sql(yes beware sql injection if you use raw). I still wish they ad something better to do this built in. I know it would add overhead to the sqlalchemy engine results object but it sure would be cleaner. I'm trying to use sqlalchemy so I can switch different backends (sqlite/postgres/mysql) and not have to change code.

```
from sqlalchemy import select, create_engine, text

engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///foo.sqlite3")

with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(text(sql))

sql "SELECT * FROM mytable"
rs = con.execute(text(sql))

rows = []
for row in rs:
    rows.append(row._mapping)
    print(rows[0])
print(rows[0]['mycolumnname'])
print(rows[1]['mycolumnname'])
```